# Picking and merging JavaScript arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, lodash

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        ProductID: 1,
        ProductName: 'MyProduct',
        Description: '.. some text here ..',
        UnwantedData: 'garbage here'
    },
    {
        ProductID: 2,
        ProductName: 'MyOtherProduct',
        Description: '.. some text here ..',
        UnwantedData: 'garbage herAe',
        GarbageField: '.. lorem ipsum ..'
    }
]
```

I also have a reference array that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        name: 'ProductId',
        map_to: 'item_id',
    },
    {
        name: 'ProductName',
        map_to: 'item_name',
    },
    {
        name: 'Description',
        map_to: 'description',
    },
]
```

What I want to do is use that reference array to basically drop the "unwanted" data (ie. the properties that aren't `name`s in the reference array) and replace the keys with whatever it's supposed to be mapped to (ie. `ProductId->item_id`).

The resulting array should look like this:

```
[
    {
        item_id: 1,
        item_name: 'MyProduct',
        description: '.. some text here ..'
    },
    {
        item_id: 2,
        item_name: 'MyOtherProduct',
        description: '.. some text here ..'
    }
]
```

### What I've done so far

Given that `ref` is the reference array and `data` is the list of products.

```
var only = _.map( ref, 'name' );
var products = [];

async.eachLimit( data, 20, function(item, cb) {

    products.push( _.pick(item, only) );
    cb();
}, function(err) {

    // .. then I iterate over the products array and manually replace each property 
    // I haven't done this yet
});
```

This code should work, but it feels a little inefficient and I want to know if there's a better way in achieving the desired resulting array since I'm going to be storing these in MongoDB.

Can anyone shed some light here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `for` loops:

```js
var result = [];
for(var i=0; i<data.length; ++i) {
  result[i] = {};
  for(var j=0; j<ref.length; ++j)
    result[i][ref[j].map_to] = data[i][ref[j].name];   
}
```

```js
var data = [
  {
    ProductID: 1,
    ProductName: 'MyProduct',
    Description: '.. some text here ..',
    UnwantedData: 'garbage here'
  }, {
    ProductID: 2,
    ProductName: 'MyOtherProduct',
    Description: '.. some text here ..',
    UnwantedData: 'garbage herAe',
    GarbageField: '.. lorem ipsum ..'
  }
];
var ref = [
  {
    name: 'ProductID',
    map_to: 'item_id',
  }, {
    name: 'ProductName',
    map_to: 'item_name',
  }, {
    name: 'Description',
    map_to: 'description',
  },
];
var result = [];
for(var i=0; i<data.length; ++i) {
  result[i] = {};
  for(var j=0; j<ref.length; ++j)
    result[i][ref[j].map_to] = data[i][ref[j].name];   
}
console.log(result);
```

Or, with ES5 array methods,

```js
data.map(function(old) {
  return ref.reduce(function(obj, assoc) {
    obj[assoc.map_to] = old[assoc.name];
    return obj;
  }, {});
});
```

```js
var data = [
  {
    ProductID: 1,
    ProductName: 'MyProduct',
    Description: '.. some text here ..',
    UnwantedData: 'garbage here'
  }, {
    ProductID: 2,
    ProductName: 'MyOtherProduct',
    Description: '.. some text here ..',
    UnwantedData: 'garbage herAe',
    GarbageField: '.. lorem ipsum ..'
  }
];
var ref = [
  {
    name: 'ProductID',
    map_to: 'item_id',
  }, {
    name: 'ProductName',
    map_to: 'item_name',
  }, {
    name: 'Description',
    map_to: 'description',
  },
];
console.log(data.map(function(old) {
  return ref.reduce(function(obj, assoc) {
    obj[assoc.map_to] = old[assoc.name];
    return obj;
  }, {});
}));
```

Comment: Wow. How does this work, though? I'm pretty much a novice JS programmer, so I'm not sure I get why this works.

Comment: [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) iterates `data`, and each item is named `old`. Then [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) iterates `ref`, each item is named `assoc`, and `obj` is the new object where we assign the data of `old` according to `assoc`. I have edited the answer to show the `for` loop equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

I usually find it easier to split objects into pairs with `_.pairs`, operate on the pairs, then turn them back into an object with `_.object`:

```
function goodPair(product_pair) {
    var k = product_pair[0];
    return refmap[k] != null;
}

function fixPair(product_pair) {
    var k = product_pair[0];
    var v = product_pair[1];
    return [refmap[k], v];
}

function trimProduct(full_product) {
    return _.object(_.pairs(full_product)
        .filter(goodPair)
        .map(fixPair));
}

console.log(data.map(trimProduct));
```

This way you can turn the entire transformation into one synchronous `map` over your product array.

Note that this is using a slightly simplified version of your `ref` here as `refmap`

```
var refmap = _.object(ref.map(function(r) {
    return [r.name, r.map_to];
}));

// OR

var refmap = {
    'ProductId': 'item_id',
    'ProductName': 'item_name',
    'Description': 'description',
};
```

Comment: Go through the documentation of underscore.js. There is several handy method that are great and time saving. http://underscorejs.org/

Comment: Absolutely, and the `_.pairs` and `_.object` methods are essential here. But it's easy to use *too much* Underscore/Lodash/etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) and [transform()](https://lodash.com/docs#transform) for this:

```
_.map(data, function(item) {
    return _.transform(ref, function(result, r) {
        result[r.map_to] = item[r.name];
    }, {});
});
```

You're mapping your `data` to a new structure. Each new item is the result of transforming the `ref` item. The `map_to` key in the new object gets the `name` value in the original collection.